# JIRA web request causes issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to to extract data from Jira via JIRA REST API from a c# application. to do so I execute this method :

```
public string RunQuery(JiraRessource resource, string project_id, int startAt, int maxResults, string method = "GET")
{
            string url = string.Format(m_BaseUrl);

            if (project_id != null)
            {
                string jql = "search?jql=project=" + project_id;
                url = string.Format("{0}{1}", url, jql);
            }

            string jqr = "&startAt=" + startAt + "&maxResults=" + maxResults;
            url = string.Format("{0}{1}", url, jqr);

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = method;

            string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
            string result = string.Empty;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return result;
                }
            }
}
```

I execute this method in a loop in order to be able to get all issues after I read that the REST API only gives 50 issues each time. I get errors such as "connection timed out" or "unable to read data from the transport connection". I searched online and all i found is that the connection to the server is lost but I do not know how to solve this.

If anyone knows anything about the reason why I'm getting this error or how to solve it, I will be very thankful.

Comment: I did not work with JIRA API but developed such APIs for our systems. There are always protection mechanisms in Web APIs. Servers always have a max result and max call per second limitations. Even if you specify bigger result count or make more calls, the server applies its own limitations in order to better serve to many clients. You should check the API's documentation, because the remote server is intentionally closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try below.  If any of these work, it will help you get to the source of the problem.

Try with a request for a small amount of data:

```
string url = "<your base url>/search?jql=startAt=1&maxResults=1&fields=created";
```

Try that same url in a web browser (log in to Jira first with the same creds you are using in your C# code)

Try with this code before the call:

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate X509certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true;
        };
```

Check the permissions in Jira for the user id you are using for the api call.